Sitemaps - Same page with different url base on language
I'm working on nuxt3 app with i18n for handling localization.
I currently have 2 supported languages, the default is en-US and its without a prefix (strategy: "prefix_except_default").
example:
BASE - /routeName/:id/:title
LOCALIZED - /lang-code/routeName/:id/:title (:title is translated to local lang ).
I am curious if I should set the base route as </loc/>, and then the localized route as rel="alternate".
OR
Should I create a completely new sitemap for translated languages ( thinking about a new one for pure organization).
Thank you in advance :)
I currently have only base sitemaps

Actually, you need to do both :) See Google's documentation on "telling Google about localized versions of your page using sitemaps".
The following code example is provided in this documentation page:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/english/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="https://www.example.de/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="https://www.example.de/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="https://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.de/deutsch/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="https://www.example.de/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="https://www.example.de/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="https://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.example.de/schweiz-deutsch/page.html</loc>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de"
               href="https://www.example.de/deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="https://www.example.de/schweiz-deutsch/page.html"/>
    <xhtml:link
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="https://www.example.com/english/page.html"/>
  </url>
</urlset>

The above example shows all 3 locales listed in the same XML sitemap, but you are free to list each locale's URLs in a separate sitemap.
Separate XML sitemaps for different site sections or languages is actually a good practice in terms of SEO, as it will allow you to filter Google Search Console's Page Indexing report by sitemap, and therefore by locale!
To do so, go to Google Search Console, click on Indexing > Pages, then click the "All known pages" dropdown, and select one of your XML sitemaps under "Filter to sitemaps". Just name your sitemaps in a smart way so you can find your way around the filters named after them :)
Hope this helps!
